# How do I read a .csv and save on different variables? C++

Tags: c++, csv, matrix

This is what I have at the moment, but i need to save the values on different variables and use them to compare different values.

The file format is something like:

Name of student;80;90;30

Name of student2;20;30;40

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){


vector<string> saveData(10); //used to save names
int n1[10], n2[10], n3[10];  //saves grades
int x=0;

ifstream  fileRead("Estudiantes.csv");

    string line;

    while(getline(fileRead,line))
    {
        stringstream  strings(line);
        string split;

        while(getline(strings, split,','))
        {
            cout<<separador<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```